# Managing web services in FlexBuilder - How does the manager work?

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, flexbuilder

In FlexBuilder 3, there are two items under the 'Data' menu to import and manage web services. After importing a webservice, I can update it with the manage option. However, the webservices seems to disappear after they are imported. The manager does however recognize that a certain WSDL URL was imported and refuses to do anything with it.

How does the manager know this, and how can I make it refresh a certain WSDL URL?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've had to post a dupe because I cant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652621/flexbuilder-web-services-list-empty

Comment: No, I never did. Thankfully, I could stop using Flex and move on to another platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your src folder of the flexbuilder project you should see the generated classes. For instance, if you use the manager to generate the proxy classes for www.example.com you should see the folders /com/example with the generated proxy classes inside.

To consume these webservices in ActionScript use the statement:

```
"import com.example.*;"
```

To consume the webservice in mxml include the .as file using:

```
<mx:Script source="yourscriptname.as"/>
```

To refresh the generated proxy classes, consuming the latest WSDL, simply open the manager and select "update".

Also, I found this [article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_ws.html) very useful for consuming web services.

I hope that helps, the question was kind of vague about the problem.