# FlexBuilder web services list empty

Tags: flexbuilder

I have a list of webservices from a Flex project. I am trying to load the project on a new machine and it has forgotten all the web services from the list.

I copied over the original settings file to :

```
 "myproject-web\.settings\webservices.xml"
```

This contains quite a lot of webservices and I don't want to have to reimport them all. This would involve deleting all the generated code and going through one by one and adding them.

The problem is that when I go to 'Data > Manage Web Services' I don't see any of these items.

So i tried the obvious :

- add a new webservice
- check that the webservices.xml file was modified. in fact the new service is appended to the contents of that file
- close and reopen Flex Builder
- the list only contains the one new service I added and not the old ones.

How can I 'trick' Flexbuilder into recognizing the other web services in the list. It must be storing a list somewhere else.

Note: This is the [same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877/managing-web-services-in-flexbuilder-how-does-the-manager-work) from months ago, but no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem too. What I had to do was copy the wsdl.xml file from the workspace's .metadata.plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.webservices folder from one computer to the other.

Personally this feels like the wrong place for this since the information about what web services are being used is part of the project not the workspace. If you examine the content of that file it even has your project name in it so it knows it is project specific data. Perhaps it is here because it is a limitation of eclipse, but I suspect not. Perhaps Adobe should consider modifying the eclipse plug-in to store this data somewhere in the project files.